# Instagram rss feeds not working?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, feed

I have used this url "`http://widget.stagram.com/rss/n/`".$account_url to fetch instagram feeds from the instagram.This was working untill today.

All of a suddenly from today no feeds are coming up.The url is returning empty data. Did they ditch widget.stagram.com  for feeds for instagram??

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.